# how to get original numbers from a list after computing the difference between to consecutive numbers

Tags: python, list, dictionary, numbers, list-comprehension

```
{0: [41, 42, 183, 186, 471, 493, 639, 642, 732, 734], 1: [477, 489, 490]}
```

consider I have a dictionary with a list as values.

I want to find the difference between two consecutive numbers in the list and if their difference is less than, say 40, I want to fetch the second consecutive number of those two numbers taken into consideration and store all such kinds of numbers in a list.

Can anyone please help me with this.

Comment: What output would you expect here and what have you tried so far?

Comment: 51: [177, 188, 201, 209, 226, 233, 250, 258, 273, 282, 299, 307, 323, 330, 347, 355, 370, 379, 395, 403, 420, 428, 444, 452, 468, 476, 492, 500, 517, 524, 541, 549, 565, 573, 589, 597, 613, 621, 637, 651, 753, 761, 776]  This is one of the data samples I generated. I want to group elements that share a common difference. If you see here the 51 represents the x coordinate and the list represents y coordinates. So, I want to group all the y coordinates which share a common difference. Is there any other method to group the numbers in the list according to the common difference?

Comment: Firstly, I mapped the key and value pair using zip function. Then I used len function in loop to find the length of each list. Later, I computed difference between consecutive elements using np.diff function. I ran into index error because I tried using list comprehension with multiple for loop statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to approach this:

```
data = {0: [41, 42, 183, 186, 471, 493, 639, 642, 732, 734], 1: [477, 489, 490]}
x = 40

{k: [b for a, b in zip(v, v[1:]) if a + x > b] for k, v in data.items()}
# {0: [42, 186, 493, 642, 734], 1: [489, 490]}
```

Or for a flat list:

```
[b for v in data.values() for a, b in zip(v, v[1:]) if a + 40 > b]
# [42, 186, 493, 642, 734, 489, 490]
```